# Saving a csv log file in internal storage

Tags: java, android

Description: I'm trying to log the data I have coming from firestore into a csv file, and I have the following methods to do it.

```
public interface ExportPojo {
String generateExportValues();
String generateExportHeaders();}
```

---

```
public static File generateCSV(Context context, Collection<? extends ExportPojo> values, Class<? extends ExportPojo> type) {
    StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
    String header;
    try {
        header = type.newInstance().generateExportHeaders();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    csv.append(header).append("\n");
    for (ExportPojo entry : values) {
        csv.append(entry.generateExportValues());
        csv.append("\n");
    }
    return writeStringToFile(context, csv.toString(), ".csv");
}
```

---

```
public static File writeStringToFile(Context context, String data, String format) {
    File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "/manage/");
    // create this directory if not already created
    dir.mkdir();
    // create the file in which we will write the contents
    String timestamp =
            new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM yyyy H-m-s", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    final File file = new File(dir, timestamp + format);
    try {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        os.write(data.getBytes());
        os.close();
        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Problem: The client would like the user to navigate the file directory, find the csv file, and open it. But after running the methods, I can't find the exported file. I've logged `csv.tostring()` and it looks like the data is okay. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: getFilesDir() is a private storage location for your app only. No other app has access or can find it. Use a different location.

Answer (score 0):

`context.getFilesDir()` give you the path for files directory that lies inside the app folder present in /data of Android which a normal user cannot access. To make the file accessible to user, you need to save it in a public directory.

You can do it like this: (the code is in kotlin but you can easily convert it in JAVA)

```
val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
val dir = File(path.absolutePath)
if(!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs()

val file = File("$path/Text.txt")
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
var content = ""    //todo: write your csv content here
val fw = FileWriter(file.absoluteFile)
val bw = BufferedWriter(fw)
bw.write(content)
bw.close()
file.renameTo(File("$path/${name}.csv"))
File("$path/Text.txt").delete()
```

You can also try writing the content directly to .csv instead of .txt but it failed for me.